# Storage racks - plastic vs Bronze inside room

Tags: storage, steel, plastic

I am thinking of putting storage racks in one of my carpeted room. I looked at the bronze one, big and heavy at costo and I thought they would not be suitable for placing on carpet because

- They are very heavy
- Design for very heavy object
- Hard to move (not easy to move for family)

Their advantage are

- Very sturdy
- Larger size and can store more stuff
- Good value for money

Which one should I consider? Esp is it ok to place this heavy weight storage racks directly on carpet in a room? Wouldn't it damage carpet?

Comment: I like the idea of the heavier duty ones.  If you go to the floor care departments at the DIY box stores they sell items just for this, kinda.  But I'm sure you can come up with a solution like the cups that go on the bottom of furniture.

Comment: What are you going to be putting on the racks, how much weight will they need to support?

Comment: Items like oven, dehumidifier, storage cases which has all my stuff and possibly books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend the heavy duty, solid racks for home. I think they are too heavy and suitable only for garage use (only if you need something that sturdy, esp the stability).

**Plastic One**
They are great for any where carpeted or garage or storage room. They are super light and are therefore best for the carpeted floors. Slight disadvantage is their racks have fixed height.

**Metal one with mesh**
I got this one for myself (from Home depot). They were not really designed for heavy weight objects and they have hooks means they are definitely not for heavy objects. But I love it, esp its usability/flexibility and how much stuff it can stack.

**Heavy duty metal racks**
I cannot recommend it for carpet use. They are extremely heavy, extremely strong and very hard to move or even carry it from store. I will recommend this for garage use only and only if you really need something that sturdy or if you like its design.

As I said I went with Metal with with mesh and I am super happy.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment that you'll be storing heavy items, it's worth it to go with a more sturdy metal rack.  If you're worried about carpet damage, dents are relatively [simple to fix with steam, ice](http://www.thriftyfun.com/tf430473.tip.html), or [other methods](http://www.homedepot.com/buy/appliances/vacuums-floor-care/roberts/carpet-groomer-with-12-inch-head-and-52-inch-handle-for-raking-matted-carpets-14617.html).  In the worst case, you'd probably prefer a few square inches of flattened carpet than your possessions broken.

Comment: We use both plastic and metal shelves in our basement for food storage.  The plastic shelf with cans on it visible dips in the middle.  You will definitely want metal shelves in your scenario.